# Qt promoting widget issue

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I would like to promote two widgets: the `QTextEdit` and `QTextBrowser` to paint something in the background.

I successfully promoted the `QTextEdit`. But I can't get the `QTextBrowser` done. I tried to promote the `QTextBrowser` to `Display` Class.

This is the code:

```
class Display : public QTextBrowser
{
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
    Display(QWidget* parent = 0);
};


Display::Display(QWidget* parent):QTextBrowser(parent)
{
    qDebug() <<"Hello. I am Display";
}
```

In the designer. It seems to be promoted but it doesn't do anything.

Then I change something for testing. I promote the `QTextBrowser` to `Foo` with header `foo.h` which does not exist anywhere in my project. Surprisingly, it let me do so. I rebuild the project and open the `ui_mainwindow.h`. I can see these code:

```
#include "foo.h"
................
foo *textBrowerOutput;
................

textBrowerOutput = new foo(centralWidget);
textBrowerOutput->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textBrowerOutput"));
textBrowerOutput->setFont(font6);
```

My program runs perfectly despite the `QTextBrowser` works as default. I don't understand why my promotion is not working. At the same time, I don't understand how `foo` can complie without error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally create a new project. Copy only .cpp , .h, the main .pro file and a .ui file to that new project. It works after rebuilding.